# Snowflake: JSON data with dynamic columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Does Snowflake support realtime JSON data ingestion into tables using Kafka Connector with varying columns without predefining the schema? Also, is there any reference to the documentation/examples related to it.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Kishore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Snowflake shines when ingesting JSON data without a predefined schema.

I just wrote about this:

- https://hoffa.medium.com/loading-reddit-comments-into-snowflake-44b9f2072a84

You'll notice that I'm reading JSON objects into a one column table - that column is a "variant" that will parse and optimize JSON objects on ingest.

Docs:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro.html

With Kafka:

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector.html